IR2110 high side MOSFET gate signal is not squared
I am trying to build an ESC for my BLDC. I am currently using this schema, built on a breadboard for my first prototype:

Here is the measured signals on VS (yellow) and HO (green) when powering with ~20 V.

The gate command for the lowside MOSFET is a "perfect" square.
Why is the signal distorted and not "perfectly" squared on HO/VS? I am doing something wrong?
Thanks for your help

Can I know the software you are using ?

Please measure the difference HO-Vs, either by math function on your oscilloscope or by connecting it across the gate-source and floating your scope.

I think Vs is the green trace and HO the yellow trace. I'd also be worried why you are not seeing a 36 volt change on Vs too. Oh, you are powering it from 20 volts yet your schematic says 36 volts <-- how very confusing. In which case your signals are fine.

As a response for @winny: I measure HO-Vs. The output is indeed a "perfect" square. After re-studying the MOSFET, I think that I got wrong how it worked. The squared signal needs to be HO-Vs, and not HO-GND
So I guess it was correct from the beginning.
Thanks

As a response for @winny: I measure HO-Vs. The output is indeed a "perfect" square. After re-studying the MOSFET, I think that I got wrong how it worked. The squared signal needs to be HO-Vs, and not HO-GND So I guess it was correct from the beginning. Thanks

In the provided waveforms we can see that ,the Ho signal is turn on slightly before the input Signal(Assumed).We also see that it repeats a pattern. If any parasitic or Miller Capacitance present the signal could be more distorted. Based on my assumption , the Bootstrap capacitor discharges quickly . Add a resistor between the Diode and Capacitor .It  helps to slow turn on of the device . If possible try to upload input signals, LO output. Thank you !!!
